# Elasticsearch licensing change

Tags: elasticsearch, version

I'm reading this [article](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing), but it's still not clear to me from which version Elasticsearch changes its license.
I am using version **7.17.3** and would like to upgrade to version **8.5.1**.
Are there any licensing changes between these versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're fine, the license change happened between 7.10.2 and 7.11.0.

If you're on 7.17 already, then the license will be the same once you upgrade to 8.5.1